# How to find the pinch direction in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

In my web app i have an div which will change the height and width based on the pinching  direction. for example if user pinch horizontally it will change width, for vertical pinch it will change the height.

I am using the gesture events

```
var scaleMe = $("#scaleMe");  
scaleMe[0].ongesturestart = function (e) {
    height = scaleMe .height();
}

scaleMe[0].ongesturechange = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();                 
    var scaleheight = (scaleMe.height() * e.scale); 
    scaleMe.height(Math.min(Math.max(scaleheight, 50), 400));
}
```

Is there any way to find the pinch direction ?

Comment: So you don't want scale? With scaling I mean the height and width remains relative. If you mean resize, don't use the pinch gesture, because the user expects a scale, not a resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly..

on "guesturestart" you should save pinch coordinates of one of gestures (or you can save all for better precision)

> var allTouches = event.originalEvent.touches;
>
> var prevTouchX = allTouches[0].pageX;
>
> var prevTouchY = allTouches[0].pageY;

then, on "guesturechange" you have to calculate, in what axis movement was longer

> var allTouches = event.originalEvent.touches;
>
> var touchX = allTouches[0].pageX;
>
> var touchY = allTouches[0].pageY;
>
> var propertyToChange = null;
>
> if (Math.abs(touchX - prevTouchX) > Math.abs(touchY - prevTouchY)) >{
>
> propertyToChange = 'width';
>
> } else {
>
> propertyToChange = 'height';
>
> }

Hope it was useful.